# Не найден путь то ли файл при запуске виртуального окружения

Tags: python

```
C:\Users\undon\miks> python manage.py runserver
python: can't open file 'C:\Users\undon\miks\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

причем виртуальное окружение другое запускает без ошибок( ее я создавал еще до этого, почему то именно новые виртуальные окружения не запускаются
я проверил название, и путь на правильность.

Comment: не понятна суть вопроса. `python manage.py runserver` при чем тут запуск виртуального окружения?

Comment: А файл `C:\Users\undon\miks\manage.py` точно существует? Может вы ошиблись в названии. Сделайте `dir C:\Users\undon\miks\manage.py` - что он скажет? Могли случайно какую-то букву на русском набрать или что-то ещё перепутать, такое бывает.

Comment: @Crazyelf, оказывается на одну папку ниже вводил так как названия были одинаковыми. всем спасибо